# How do I use methods in classes decorated with DataContractAttribute in a WCF Client?

Tags: .net, wcf, metadata, datacontract

I'm writing a .net WCF service.  I've written a few classes that I want to return to the calling code from the WCF service; hence, I decorate them with the `DataContract` attribute.

Let's suppose that my WCF service is called `FooService`.  It contains a method called `FooMethod` which returns an object of type `FooData` (which is decorated with the `DataContract` attribute.  Suppose that `FooData` contains a list of numbers and a method called `FooAverage` which returns the average value of the numbers.

In Visual Studio, I create a new application to consume the service.  I add a new "Service Reference" to my WCF Service and give it the namespace `myWcfService`.  In my client code, I instantiate a proxy class and get a connection to the service.  To get the `FooData` object from my proxy, the method call is `myWcfService.FooMethod()`.  It returns an object of type `myWcfService.FooData`, which is a type determined from the `FooService` metadata.

Now that I have my object of type `myWcfService.FooData`, how can I get this data into an object of type `FooData` as the original type from the service code so that I can call `FooData.FooAverage()`?

**Edit:** I am entirely aware of the fact that data comes down the pipe in XML format and that the logic of the methods in a class decorated with `DataContract` does not get returned by the service; it isn't serializable.  What I'm asking is: if I can reference the class that contains the `DataContract` class used in the service, is there a straightforward way to de-serialize the data into the class that it was serialized from?

I am willing to accept the answer that it is not possible with the current .net framework.

Answer (score 2):

WCF will allow types to be re-used if they are contained in the project.  If your data types are in a `Common` project somewhere then those types are re-serialized (so long as they have a default constructor and are marked for serialization).

That's only half your question though. If you want your datatype to proxy to the server the method call implementation then you might want Remoting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973857.aspx) and use a Proxy object.

Comment: I would avoid Remoting - WCF has made this obsolete. Adding operations to the service contract is the way to do this in WCF. However, as I read the question, this is not something he asked about.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

You need to keep two things **completely** separate:

- you have **service contracts** which define the methods (decorated with `[OperationContract]` attributes)
- those methods might need class types, which you define using `[DataContract]` attributes

The nature of WCF is that the parameters and types going from client to server are serialized into an XML representation - so all you can send across the wire in the form of data contracts is raw data - **no behavior** - you **cannot** send across a DataContract class and call a method on it.

In a normal setup, your client-side data classes are not even the same type as they are on the server side - they just *look* the same in their XML serialized format. All they share is their XML serialization - the data elements that get serialized, nothing more. WCF is **not** some remote-procedure call method - it sends data-only messages between client and server (and that's a *good thing*! (tm) ).

If you need to be able to call a method, add that method to your **service contract** as a method decorated with the `[OperationContract]` attribute.

Comment: -1 Of course he can use his original (service-side defined) FooData type on the client side if he wants to (as Nat Zauggs answer explains), and call methods on it. The question makes clear that he's asking about a method which operates on the serializable state of the object: since the state is serialized at the service and deserialized back into the object at the client, the method will work correctly on the client just as it did on the server. Of course, if a method depends on private non-serializable state, then the same does not apply.

Comment: @Chris Dickson: this would be highly discouraged and very bad practice - I would say: just **don't ever** do it!

Comment: The questioner asked was it possible. It is. As regards whether it's good practice or not: I would agree with you that in any usage where client and service aren't developed (and versioned) together, its a bad idea to share types between them. BUT, WCF was designed not just for SOA but also to replace existing IPC and intra-process comms mechanisms (such as Remoting), and in some scenarios this would be an entirely reasonable design decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend myWcfService.FooData with a partial class definition and define FooAverage() in the client, if the original FooAverage() doesn't have any dependencies that prohibit this:

```
partial class FooData
{
  public double FooAverage() { return Math.Average(Numbers); }
}
```

But remember that FooData is a data transfer object, and as such does not have any private state, which means that you can put all the data into non-member functions anyway:

```
double average = Math.Average(foodata.Numbers);
```